# I have a huge List of If statements and want to clean up my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This is 4th day learning how to code, I'm still a little confused about some of the basics.It has pygame, pygame.text,  So essentially my code looks like this.

```
#Mouse click to get mouse Position
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if gamestage == 0 and gamestage <= 1:
            gamestage += 1
            mx, my =pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #Total rectangle dimentions mx>806 and mx<889 and my>890 and my<920
        #Clickable squares for Shots and Team
        #Use print function if bug arises
            if mx>848 and mx<889 and my>890 and my<920:

                #numberonscreen_x=859
                #numberonscreen_y=905
                n+=1
                print(n)
                n=str(n)
                text_surface, rect = gamefont.render(n,(4, 8, 18))
                n=int(n)
                screen.blit(board,(0,0))
                pygame.display.flip()

            if mx>806 and mx<848 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>764 and mx<806 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>722 and mx<764 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>680 and mx<722 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>638 and mx<680 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>596 and mx<638 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>554 and mx<596 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>512 and mx<554 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>470 and mx<512 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>428 and mx<470 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>386 and mx<428 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>344 and mx<386 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>302 and mx<344 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>260 and mx<302 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>218 and mx<260 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>176 and mx<218 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
            if mx>134 and mx<176 and my>890 and my<920:
                print("Pass")
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if gamestage != 0:
            gamestage = 0

    #Press 0 set given on screen button to zero
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_0:
        mx, my =pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if mx>848 and mx<889 and my>905 and my<920:
            n=0
            print(n)
        if mx>806 and mx<848 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>764 and mx<806 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>722 and mx<764 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>680 and mx<722 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>638 and mx<680 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>596 and mx<638 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>554 and mx<596 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>512 and mx<554 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>470 and mx<512 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>428 and mx<470 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>386 and mx<428 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>344 and mx<386 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>302 and mx<344 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass")
        if mx>260 and mx<302 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>218 and mx<260 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>176 and mx<218 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
        if mx>134 and mx<176 and my>905 and my<920:
            print("Pass1")
```

Which looks really bad. I'm making a monopoly game and I am adding 2 onscreen buttons for  each property. Meaning that there will be over 100 different sets of (mx,my). It looks very inefficient just based on looking around at other people's code. Since there will be so many different clickable sections of the board I need to find a way to both make it more efficient and easier to read.

Although it would be nice for someone to "just do it" I'd much rather have a response with a lot of links. With this method I would need also 100 text_surfaces with different names, 100 different variable n's. My thought process is making something to store all n's, text_surfaces and recalling it. However I don't really know how to do that what to call it and whether or not it "import from" might work.

Comment: If this code *works*, this is rather a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi Steven, welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good question and there are certainly things we can show you to improve, but it's in the wrong place. Your code works, you just want to make it better and are looking for people to review it. The place for that is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Could you move it there please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This site is about code which does _not_ work, so if you have a question about coding style, you might want to ask it on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hint: the `my` check is always the same, you could do that in one `if my ...:` at the top and not repeat it every time. For `mx`, you only seem to want to *exclude* certain numbers like `806`, `764` etc, so you could do `if mx not in (806, 764, ...)`. But overall, there's probably a better algorithm/approach to be found here.

Comment: Sorry about how would I delete the post?

Comment: Anytime you have 100 of *anything*, you should be thinking in terms of data structures. Put all your clickable objects in a list, and check them all with a loop instead of checking each one individually.

Comment: Steven: I disagree with @deceze and think it would be OK for you to leave your question posted here. I added a "pygame" tag, because the module may include something to help with a (fairly common) problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize an array of `mx` ranges:

```
mx_ranges = [
    (806,848),
    (764,806),
    (722,764),
    (680,722),
    (638,680),
    (596,638),
    (554,596),
    (512,554),
    (470,512),
    (428,470),
    (386,428),
    (344,386),
    (302,344),
    (260,302),
    (218,260),
    (176,218),
    (134,176),
]
```

And then use this function instead of each one of those "large `if` chunks":

```
def check_mx_range(mx, min_my, max_my, result):
    for mx_range in mx_ranges:
        if mx_range[0] < mx < mx_range[1] and min_my < my < max_my:
            print(result)
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I wanted to simulate the numbers of clicks and I ended up figuring out why the site is called stackoverflow. I forgot to add how many times the loop goes throw so it gave me the error. Essentially I made a function within a function within a function...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some levels of [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)).

Let's start with a base skeleton of a pygame game:

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    rects = []
    dt = 0

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update(dt, events)
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What we want to achieve is [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), so let's keep our main loop clean and simple. We handle events (and the only events the main loop cares about is `QUIT`), we update our game state (which is the [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) of sprites named `sprites`), we draw stuff to the screen and we limit the framerate with a [`Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

So, you say you have a monopoly board, so let's think of a way to represent this. Let's create a list of properties, each with a color, a name, and a price:

```
properties = (
    ('purple', 100, 'Oriental Avenue'),
    ('purple', 200, 'Vermont Avenue'),
    ('purple', 300, 'Connecticut Avenue'),
    ('white',  400, 'Atlantic Avenue'),
    ('white',  500, 'Ventnor Avenue'),
    ('white',  600, 'Marvin Gardens'),
    ('blue',   700, 'Park Place'),
    ('blue',   800, 'Boadwalk')
)
```

Note how that's just a list of some data (actually it's a tuple of tuples), since we want [Separation Of Data And Code](http://wiki.c2.com/?SeparationOfDataAndCode).

The properties a part of the game state. Let's create a class that contains all the game state and creates some [sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) for us that we use to draw stuff to the screen. This class will also calculate the position of each sprite.

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, properties, font):
        self.properties = properties
        self.sprites = []

        side = len(properties) / 4 + 1
        size = (side * PROP_SIZE.width, side * PROP_SIZE.height)

        x, y = 0, 0
        flow = 'r'
        for prop in properties:
            if flow == 'r':
                if x == side - 1:
                    flow = 'd'
                else:
                    x += 1

            if flow == 'd':
                if y == side - 1:
                    flow = 'l'
                else:
                    y += 1

            if flow == 'l':
                if x == 0:
                    flow = 'u'
                else:
                    x -= 1

            if flow == 'u':
                y -= 1

            self.sprites.append(Property(*prop, (x*PROP_SIZE.width, y*PROP_SIZE.height), font))
```

We want each property to have two buttons, so let's creat the sprite class `Property` that will handle the event checking for use:

```
class Property(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, price, name, pos, font):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface(PROP_SIZE.size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (0, 0, 0), self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, pygame.Color(color), self.rect.inflate(-2, -2))
        self.color = color
        self.price = price
        self.name = name

        font.render_to(self.image, (11, 21), name, pygame.Color('black'))
        font.render_to(self.image, (10, 20), name, pygame.Color('white'))

        self.buttons = {
            'A': pygame.Rect(10, 100, 100, 20),
            'B': pygame.Rect(10, 125, 100, 20),
        }

        self.rect.topleft = pos

    def update(self, dt, events):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for button in self.buttons:
            hovered = self.buttons[button].move(*self.rect.topleft).collidepoint(pos)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.image, pygame.Color('red' if hovered else 'darkgrey'), self.buttons[button])

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for button in self.buttons:
                    hovered = self.buttons[button].move(*self.rect.topleft).collidepoint(pos)
                    if hovered:
                        print(f'{self.name} says: You clicked {button}')
```

We use some nice pygame stuff like the [Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) class and it's [inflate](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate), [move](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) and [collidepoint](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) methods so we don't have to calculate positions/collisions ourself.

Here's the full, running code. You'll get the idea:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

PROP_SIZE = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 120, 180)

class Property(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, price, name, pos, font):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface(PROP_SIZE.size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (0, 0, 0), self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, pygame.Color(color), self.rect.inflate(-2, -2))
        self.color = color
        self.price = price
        self.name = name

        font.render_to(self.image, (11, 21), name, pygame.Color('black'))
        font.render_to(self.image, (10, 20), name, pygame.Color('white'))

        self.buttons = {
            'A': pygame.Rect(10, 100, 100, 20),
            'B': pygame.Rect(10, 125, 100, 20),
        }

        self.rect.topleft = pos

    def update(self, dt, events):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for button in self.buttons:
            hovered = self.buttons[button].move(*self.rect.topleft).collidepoint(pos)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.image, pygame.Color('red' if hovered else 'darkgrey'), self.buttons[button])

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for button in self.buttons:
                    hovered = self.buttons[button].move(*self.rect.topleft).collidepoint(pos)
                    if hovered:
                        print(f'{self.name} says: You clicked {button}')

class Board:
    def __init__(self, properties, font):
        self.properties = properties
        self.sprites = []

        side = len(properties) / 4 + 1
        size = (side * PROP_SIZE.width, side * PROP_SIZE.height)

        x, y = 0, 0
        flow = 'r'
        for prop in properties:
            if flow == 'r':
                if x == side - 1:
                    flow = 'd'
                else:
                    x += 1

            if flow == 'd':
                if y == side - 1:
                    flow = 'l'
                else:
                    y += 1

            if flow == 'l':
                if x == 0:
                    flow = 'u'
                else:
                    x -= 1

            if flow == 'u':
                y -= 1

            self.sprites.append(Property(*prop, (x*PROP_SIZE.width, y*PROP_SIZE.height), font))


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 14)
    font.origin = True

    properties = (
        ('purple', 100, 'Oriental Avenue'),
        ('purple', 200, 'Vermont Avenue'),
        ('purple', 300, 'Connecticut Avenue'),
        ('white',  400, 'Atlantic Avenue'),
        ('white',  500, 'Ventnor Avenue'),
        ('white',  600, 'Marvin Gardens'),
        ('blue',   700, 'Park Place'),
        ('blue',   800, 'Boadwalk')
    )

    board = Board(properties, font)
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(*board.sprites)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    rects = []
    dt = 0

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update(dt, events)
        screen.fill(pygame.Color('darkgrey'))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]